# "No resource identifier found for attribute". I cant fix it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:CircleProgressView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hobci.fitnessapp.MainActivity">

    <at.grabner.circleprogress.CircleProgressView
        android:id="@+id/circleProgressView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"

        CircleProgressView:cpv_value="0"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_maxValue="59"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_barWidth="10dp"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_rimWidth="2dp"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_contourSize="0dp"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_autoTextSize="true"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_seekMode="true"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_unit="sec"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_unitPosition="right_top"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_unitScale="1"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_textScale="1"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_showUnit="true"
        CircleProgressView:cpv_autoTextColour="@color/circleProgressViewTextColor"

        />

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chronometer"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity class layout file. For some reason it doesn't compile as it cant find the resources it needs:

> C:\Users\hobci\AndroidStudioProjects\FitnessApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
>
> Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'cpv_autoTextColour' in package 'com.example.hobci.fitnessapp'
>
> C:\Users\hobci\AndroidStudioProjects\FitnessApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
>
> Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'cpv_autoTextColour' in package 'com.example.hobci.fitnessapp'
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

These are the three errors that occur and I have tried changing /res to /lib but that didn't work. This is for a Stopwatch just to let you know.

Comment: It's spelled `cpv_autoTextColor`; no `u` in `Color` – https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View/blob/master/CircleProgressView/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L10. And it's a `boolean`, apparently, not a color value.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `res-> values` there should be a `colors.xml` file, open it, make sure the value its there:

[image]

you can also set it programatically with `.setTextColorAuto(true); //previous set values are ignored`